# My 2D Character is not jumping at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am having an issue with my character which is not jumping at all. I am new to Unity, but I made sure to apply the script to the player and adjust the speed, I did not touch the Rigidbody 2D. If any one can help me figure our the issue, it will be much appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public float moveSpeed;
public float jumpSpeed;
public bool grounded = false;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update () {

    transform.Translate (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

    if (grounded) 
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump"))
        {
            rb.AddForce (Vector2.up * jumpSpeed);
            grounded = false;
        }
    }
}


void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll){
    if (coll.transform.tag == "Ground") 
    {
        grounded = true;
    }
}

}
```

Inspector window of the Player GameObject

[image: Player]

Inspector window of the Ground GameObject

[image: Ground/Cube]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you haven't tag the Ground GameObject as so. So in the `OnCollisionEnter2D` the character detects the collision, but the  `if (coll.transform.tag == "Ground")` will never be true. So it means the character can't be `grounded`

Since to be grounded is the first condition to check if the player pressed the Jump key. It is impossible it will ever jump

```
if (grounded) 
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump"))
        {
            rb.AddForce (Vector2.up * jumpSpeed);
            grounded = false;
        }
    }
```

To solve this issue: **You need to tag the Ground GameObject as so**. In case you are not sure how to do that, on the Tag menu, create (if it doesnt exist already) a new tag called Ground. Then assign in that same menu the Ground Tag to the Ground GameObject. Here you can learn how in case you need a visual reference:

[image]

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html

Edit: You can try this script if everything fails. It should work. I used my self some time ago, I cleaned the code so to leave only what you need to move the character in the x and y axis. Hope to have included everything you need:

```
public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour {

    // LayerMask to determine what is considered ground for the player
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    // Transform just below feet for checking if player is grounded
    public Transform groundCheck;

    // store references to components on the gameObject
    Transform transform;
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    bool isGrounded = false;

    float vy;
    float vx;

    public float jumpForce = 600f;

    void Awake () {
        transform = GetComponent<Transform> ();
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }


    void Update()
    {

        // determine horizontal velocity change based on the horizontal input
        vx = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
        vy = rigidbody.velocity.y;

        // Check to see if character is grounded by raycasting from the middle of the player
        // down to the groundCheck position and see if collected with gameobjects on the
        // whatIsGround layer
        isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, groundCheck.position, whatIsGround);

        if(isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) // If grounded AND jump button pressed, then allow the player to jump
        {
            DoJump();
        }

        // Change the actual velocity on the rigidbody
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(_vx * MoveSpeed, _vy);

    }

    //Make the player jump
    void DoJump()
    {
        // reset current vertical motion to 0 prior to jump
        vy = 0f;
        // add a force in the up direction
        rigidbody.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpForce));

    }
}
```

So things to take into account:

- Instead of tag the ground, you create a layer with everything you
  consider ground. That will include possible platforms the character
  may jump over. Pass as a parameter this layer to the script in the
  inspector
- You need to place an empty GameObject in the feet of the character.
  You will drag and drop that GameObject in the editor onto the
  groundCheck public variable.
- Instead of OnTriggerEnter, you will use `Physics2D.Linecast` which
  will trave a line from the position of the character to under its
  feet (where you should have place the Transform mentioned in the
  previous step) and if in the middle there is an element of the
  groundLayer, it means the character will be grounded.

Let me know if anything is not clear or if you find some bug.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, but I did try that now, and it did not work.

Comment: I'll start from scratch and redo it, and see if that works.

Comment: @KonoDioDa I edited my answer with a script you may use as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the script, but I managed to redo some parts in Unity, and change things around my script to use different things, and got it to work.

Comment: @KonoDioDa Im glad you did it. I would appreciate if you accept my answer

Comment: Totally forgot about that, and it done! However, I have a question for the animation. I animated my character to move right and left, and set them up in the animator and in my script. So now my character is moving right and back to idle state, but he is not accessing the left animation. Do you know what may be causing this? Sorry to ask here, its just for some reason I am not allowed to post questions.

Comment: @KonoDioDa with animation you mean the character sprite looks to the left? or is it a more complex animation. And yeah better try to ask a new question with it, to place there possible solutions and scripts, because if we make this longer they may tell us off. They want the site a Question & Answer format, but not longer conversations like forum style.

Comment: Alright, I'll try and post a new question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Mention me in a comment, and I will try to find a solution

Comment: I have posted the question, and mentioned you, but wasn't sure you got it. But just in case I'll link the url here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46268750/2d-character-left-animation-is-not-being-accessed

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned your problem is deffinetly that your missing to tag your ground object :)

A tip: What i like to do when i have problems like this is to use the unitys Debug.Log() to locate where the problem is it. It will let you know easily in the console what code is run and which is not. Try do the following:

void Update () {

```
transform.Translate (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

if (grounded) 
{
    Debug.Log("Is grounded");

    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Jump clicked");
        rb.AddForce (Vector2.up * jumpSpeed);
        grounded = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but as for the tag, I did try that now, and it did not work.

Comment: Also from the Debug it says at first that it is grounded, and when i press jump, it says "Jump was pressed" but apparently it doesn't go up or down :( However, I'll just start from scratch and redo it. Maybe I made mistake along the way in the unity, than the script.