# 2D Character, left animation is not being accessed

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, animator

I have issue in Unity with my 2D characters animation. I simply made the animation of it walking right and left. I set things up in the animator, and for some reason the right animation is being accessed, but not the left whenever I press "A". 
This is the code part of animation of my PlayerController script:

```
anim.SetFloat("mSpeed", Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x));
```

[Animator Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL1cp.png)

Comment: @Ignacio Alorre Here is an image of my animator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what to do instead of using left animation, I just used the Sprite Render to Flip.X when the "A" key is pressed. And it works!